# "Terminated due to Memory Error" when trying to make a GIF in Cocoa with Swift

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift, animated-gif

I'm attempting to create an animated GIF out of an `NSArray` of `UIImage`s and am consistanty getting a "Terminated due to Memory Error" message as soon as I call `let saved: Bool = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)`. Each `UIImage` object is 500w x 500h. While I'm new to Swift, I've been through the `CGImageDestination` docs over and over and I think I have things set up correctly.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

```
func makeGIFWithImagesArray(theArray: NSArray) -> NSData {

    var gifData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    var destination: CGImageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(gifData, kUTTypeGIF, UInt(theArray.count), nil)

    let delayProps: NSDictionary = [NSNumber(float: 0.2) : kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime]
    let frameProps: NSDictionary = [delayProps : kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary]

    var miscProps: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    miscProps.setObject(NSNumber(bool: true), forKey: kCGImagePropertyGIFHasGlobalColorMap as NSString)
    miscProps.setObject(NSNumber(int: 0), forKey: kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as NSString)
    miscProps.setObject(NSNumber(bool: false), forKey: kCGImagePropertyHasAlpha as NSString)
    miscProps.setObject(NSNumber(float: 1.0), forKey: kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality as NSString)

    let gifProps: NSDictionary = [miscProps : kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary]

    for image in theArray {
        let imageRef: CGImageRef = image.CGImage
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, imageRef, frameProps)
    }

    CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, gifProps)
    let saved: Bool = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)

    return gifData

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are using too many pictures or too detailed of pictures and eating up all the memory. You could try this same function with a lower amount of pictures or with less detailed pictures and see if that stops the memory warning. If it does, then you have found the problem.